# What is the unit of travel time and speed in Veins?

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I'm working on Veins in OMNeT++, by using TraCI commands to get the travel time of roads using this method:

```
double getCurrentTravelTime().
```

The value which I get from this is very small. So I wondered what the unit of travel time is and also how to get the mean speed in SuMO or Veins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This commands queries variable `0x5a` from an edge. Its meaning is documented on the SUMO wiki, on page http://www.sumo.dlr.de/wiki/TraCI/Edge_Value_Retrieval:

> current travel time (0x5a): double, Returns the current travel time (length/mean speed).

Where not specified otherwise, SUMO uses the [international system of units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units), that is, the return value is in seconds.